# Run mvn release:prepare through Java code

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, maven-release-plugin

I'm working on executing a set of maven commands through Java code after programatically checking out svn project using SVNKit API and I'm facing some strange issues as described below -

Here's my Java code to invoke maven command -

```
public static void runCommand(String mavenCommand, File workingDirectory) 
throws IOException {
    ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(getMavenCommand(), 
                                                       "release:prepare");
    processBuilder.directory(workingDirectory);
    Process process = processBuilder.start();
        try {
            process.waitFor();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
   }

protected static String getMavenCommand() {
    String cmd = (System.getProperty("os.name")
                               .startsWith("Windows")) ? "mvn.bat" : "mvn";
    String mavenHome = "C:/Program Files (x86)/apache-maven-3.2.1/bin/";
    return mavenHome + cmd;
}
```

**release:prepare** command expects the user to hit 'ENTER' for three questions - the name of the tag, release version and development version and when this code is run through Eclipse (I redirected the output to stdout) I can see on the console that the program just hangs and doesn't proceed further as maven expects users to hit 'ENTER' manually for the questions asked, then I manually terminated the Java program through Eclipse after which the sub-process created still ran and generated my tag appropriately, I tried terminating the Java program by using System.exit(0) but this terminates all the sub-processes as well stopping maven life-cycle execution.

Things I tried so far -

1) Passed the arguments directly for the tag name, release version and the next development version - **"release:prepare -Dtag=my-proj-1.10 -DreleaseVersion=4.1.12 -DdevelopmentVersion=4.1.13-SNAPSHOT"** but the program complained of an **invalid maven life-cycle**.

2) Tried using mvn-invoker from mvn shared plugin's API's to run maven goals as per this post - https://tfesenko.com/2015/10/09/running-maven-tasks-from-java-code/ and added this dependency in the pom -

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.shared/maven-
     shared-components -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.shared</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-shared-components</artifactId>
  <version>16</version>
</dependency>
```

but the required dependency wasn't being downloaded and put on the java build path.

Is it better to use mvn-invoker to execute maven goals or is the old Java Process way much better? If mvn:invoker then from where can I download the dependency jar **maven-shared-components** to put it on the build path?

What am I doing wrong in the Java ProcessBuilder code above?

Comment: You're getting out of the box man... You should create a maven plugin instead of call a **.bat** file in your code.

Comment: Whatever I have is actually a maven plugin, so in this case can I directly execute the mvn command on my checked out project?

Comment: I would suggest to hardly think about a CI solution like Jenkins which handles all those things...

Comment: Yes I agree with you and I did look into Jenkins and looks like the best way to achieve CI/CD but in my case this project is more than 10 yrs old and the legacy process would need to be remodeled completely and this would take some significant amount of time, meanwhile while I work on Jenkins part I wanted to take this much simpler route. Can someone give their opinion on the above code?

Comment: I don't see that you safe something if you do the work for CI/CD also for the legacy part. The link to the maven-invoker shard component is here: http://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-invoker/ (But this is intended as a plexus component)..Apart from that what is so complicated about: `mvn -B release:prepare release:perform`? Or doing that via shell/bat script ?